# How to get the Bronze Editor Badge

Tags: support, editing, badges

I was trying to get the [Bronze Editor badge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/3/editor), so I edited one post by fixing a few grammar errors and making the question clearer. However, I thought editing was a privilege only earned at 2000 rep?

After I submitted my edit, I got a message saying it would only be displayed once peer reviewed.  Will I still get the editor badge no matter what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll get the badge if and only if the edit gets approved by the reviewers in the [Suggested Edits queue](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits). In your particular case, [the edit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/168503) is approved, and you have accordingly received the badge.

For more information, see [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges).

Answer (score 2):

Editing without having the edit reviewed is a privilege earned with 2000 reputation. But you can always *suggest* an edit, regardless of how much reputation you have. (Even without being logged in!) When you suggest an edit, if you don't have 2000 rep, your edit suggestion is placed in a queue to be reviewed by high-reputation users, and if they approve it, then it goes through as a normal edit. Whereas if you have 2000 rep or more when you submit the edit suggestion, it just goes through as an edit without any separate approval needed.